# What does the Override attribute on the OrderBy of a CAML query do?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In the documentation of the OrderBy element, I see an Override field.  What does the FALSE value do?  What does the TRUE value do?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467378.aspx

```
<OrderBy  Override = "TRUE" | "FALSE"  UseIndexForOrderBy = "TRUE" | "FALSE">
</OrderBy>
```